# Shower manifold diverter stem removal question

Tags: plumbing, removal, diverter

How the heck does this Stem come out of the threaded tube that the escutcheon goes over? The Hot and cold stems have bonnet nuts bet not the diverter.[image]

Comment: You should provide more details and other pars associated with it.

Comment: Should be a Phillips screw in the center or set screw on back side